# How to draw smooth looking lines on Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I want to make a simple drawing app using Tkinter, I want to draw lines using my mouse, the solution that I came up with works fine, and I can even draw multiple lines but in the picture below you can see that lines look jagged. My question is can I draw smooth looking lines on Tkinter?

[image: Example of multiple line drawing and the issue]

Here is the code that I am using to draw lines on the canvas:

```
import tkinter as tk


class DrawingApp:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self.master, width=1024, height=256)
        self.canvas.pack()

        self.previous_coordinates = None
        self.canvas.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.draw)
        self.canvas.bind("<Button-3>", self.erase)
        self.canvas.bind("<Button-1>", self.draw)
        self.canvas.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.reset)

    def draw(self, event):
        if self.previous_coordinates:
            x1, y1 = self.previous_coordinates
            x2, y2 = event.x, event.y
            self.canvas.create_line(x1, y1, x2, y2, fill="black", width=20, capstyle=tk.PROJECTING,
                                    joinstyle=tk.BEVEL, smooth=True, splinesteps=36)
        self.previous_coordinates = (event.x, event.y)

    def erase(self, event):
        # delete every drawing in the canvas
        self.canvas.delete("all")

    def reset(self, event):
        self.previous_coordinates = None


root = tk.Tk()
app = DrawingApp(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Try changing `capstyle` to `tk.ROUND` and it may improve the smoothness a bit.  Also the `smooth` and `splinesteps` are useless for drawing line between two points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing `capstyle` option to `tk.ROUND` and it may improve the smoothness a bit.

Note also that `smooth` and `splinesteps` options are useless of a straight line between two points.

```py
self.canvas.create_line(x1, y1, x2, y2, fill="black", width=20, 
                        capstyle=tk.ROUND, joinstyle=tk.BEVEL)
```

Result:

[image]